# PHP API not matching

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, php-5.4

I need to enable a module installed on my system. I have installed PHP 5.4 from ondrej's repository couple of months ago ago and now I have compiled ODBTP module from the source.

Unfortunately, if only I enable this module I receive an error causing all the PHP scripts failure:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: odbtp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I think i understand what it's trying to tell me, I wanted to compile PHP from source, so that it would have matching version of API, however I can't find the source for my version of PHP...

If you need any more details, I will be glad to provide them.

Comment: If you managed to compile module, then you have something like php5-dev installed. Why you have different php5 and php5-dev versions installed? Why don't you upgrade dev or downgrade php5?

Comment: because I can't get php5-dev package in version 5.4.17  I can't downgrade php5 package to 4.3 version that matches php5-dev version, as I badly need the support for pdo-dblib that was bugged in php 5.3

Comment: Ok, I've managed to install php5-dev in the same version as my php. I have recompiled the extension, but still - i receive the same error... looks like somewhere on the system the old version is still linked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill ondrej's repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or wherever it is.
2. `purge` your PHP instalation
3. Download the version of PHP that you need from [php.net](http://www.php.net/downloads.php#v5.4.19) or better yet the latest from 5.4.x (5.4.19)
4. Compile it with support for all modules that you need

Your Ubuntu is not supported any-more, so you don't have too much other options than compiling from source. If it is a server the steps should be the other way arround. :D

@khartvin updating that server to 12.04 would also pose a big risk and would probably break things. Stuff changes between OS versions - a lot, especially with Ubuntu!
And sometimes configuration management is not good at all with Canonical.

If you want to update it is best to jump between versions:

```
10.04 updt-> 10.10 updt-> 11.04 updt-> 11.10 updt-> 12.04
```

and still it may fail, so this is not a solution.

Compiling from source on the server does not mean that you need to have downtime for the whole compilation - you don't need to compile over the current installation. You can compile to other dirs and then switch the webserver settings.

At this point **your best option is** to migrate the server as a whole. So communicate this to your clients. This is what you'd generally need to do in order to relocate:
(A lot of this depends on your set-up and this is just a general single-server example)

- Prepare the new machine: SELinux, locales, users/groups, Apache, etc
- Install and configure php with what you need
- Install databases, copy info, prepare to copy again just before DNS switch
- If you have SSL you will also have to manage that
- Get your web application running on the new machine
- Have **someone else** test it to verify everything is running
- In some late evening in the timezone of your users: stop the web app, copy the db, change dns records to point to new server and in about 10 mins to 2 hours max your users will be on the new server.

The refresh time of DNS records depends on your provider - in most cases it happens almost immediately.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought. Unfortunately that is a customer's production server.  It cannot have a PHP installation purged + even if I purged it behind their back - I am terrified about building whole tree of dependencies after installing PHP from source...  I just wish I could update that server to 12.04... :(